# Priority of AND and OR operator in Mysql select query

Tags: mysql, operator-precedence

I have a written a `mysql select query` to fetch schedule details based on origin states,origin city,destination state and destination city. In my query i have used `AND` and `OR` operator.

Here is my query,

```
SELECT * FROM TruckLoadSchedule ts 
WHERE ts.originState IN (states) AND ts.originCity IN (cities) 
   OR ts.destState IN (states) AND ts.destCity IN (cities);
```

But I need to know the priority of AND and OR operator in the above query, i mean to say will it do something like this `(X AND Y) OR (M AND Q)` internally?

Comment: and why don't you just use the brackets? You can use brackets in sql!

Comment: A forum is not a way to avoid using [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operator-precedence.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, AND has higher precedence than OR.  x and y are bound together, m and q are bound together, then the resulting expressions are ORed.

Comment: so i don't need to add any extra bracket in my query?. I mean now it is like this x AND y OR M AND Q, if i add brackets it will be like this (x AND y) OR (M AND Q).

Comment: Brackets will probably help the readability, but it'll work fine without them.

Comment: That is implied by this answer. You don't need to keep asking the same question.

Comment: @SamDufel Thnx for your answer and patience to explain the things.

Comment: @EJP There is nothing wrong in asking if you are not clear enough.

Comment: It's hard to see what part of 'yes' you didn't understand, or what part of 'higher precedence' either.

Answer (score 1):

AND has a higher priority than OR in every programming language I have ever seen, and I've seen several dozen at close quarters, and implemented a few myself. This question was basically settled in 1960 with the Algol-60 report, if not already in Fortran (1957).

[There was one exception but it was a mis-implemented language with no operator precedence at all. I fixed that.]

Comment: +1 for the thumb rule.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will do something like `(X AND Y) OR (M AND Q)`. `AND` operator's priority is higher than `OR`.

For more see [MySQL: Operator Precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html)