# MYSQL AND & OR priority

Tags: mysql, operator-precedence

I know its recomended to use parenthesis to separate `and` ,`or` statements.but I'm wondering how mysql engine does render statements without parenthesis.lets say we have this statement:

`select * from users where A and B or C and D;`

how would it be with parenthesis?

Comment: **[Operator Precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html)** First `AND` then `OR`. Same as in algebra `A*B + C*D`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql or/and precedence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345569/mysql-or-and-precedence)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AND has higher priority than OR.

```
select * from users where (A and B) or (C and D);
```

Refer to: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html

Answer (score 4):

It is like in math expressions:

```
AND is like a PRODUCT
OR is like a SUM
```

so AND are executed before OR, unless differently indicated through parenthesis, like in math again.

Answer (score 1):

**AND** has higher precedence than **OR**.

[Priority of AND and OR operator in Mysql select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249865/priority-of-and-and-or-operator-in-mysql-select-query)

[Operator Precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html)